# how to get properties from outlook in Sharepoint

Tags: 2013

I want to get all properties of User profile that are visible in Outlook. in Below there is Site, Emp No these are accessible using below code.

```
var currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
            SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(currentWeb.Site);
            String username = currentUser.LoginName;
            UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
            if (profileManager.UserExists(username))
            {
                UserProfile currentUserProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(username);
                string departmentName = (string)currentUserProfile["Site"].Value;
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you synchronized those properties from AD to SharePoint User Profile Service?

Comment: yes that was the Issue. the properties are not sync. for now I am getting properties directly from AD (not using UserProfileManager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Jussi for your comment "Have you synchronized those properties from AD to SharePoint User Profile Service? "

I was able to get properties using below code.

```
var currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
        SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(currentWeb.Site);
        String username = currentUser.LoginName;
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
        string connection = "LDAP://ads." + currentWeb.Url.Substring(currentWeb.Url.IndexOf('/') + 2);

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher(connection);
            dssearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + currentUser.LoginName.Substring(currentUser.LoginName.IndexOf('\\') + 1) + ")";
            SearchResult sresult = dssearch.FindOne();
            if (sresult != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry dsresult = sresult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                string location = dsresult.Properties["l"][0].ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location) || !location.Equals("Abu Dhabi"))
                {
                    Page.Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString() + "\\Pages\\AccessDenied.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Page.Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString() + "\\Pages\\AccessDenied.aspx");
            }
        });
```